# Android: system notification icon

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm developing an Android application that implements a vpn service. 
During the lifetime of a VPN connection, a system-managed notification is shown, as is reported on the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html

This notification actually seems to show the icon I provided as application icon, but I noticed that the icon is resized on some devices and its ratio is modified. I made the various launcher icons (ldpi,mdpi...xxxhdpi) according to the size here: http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Where am I wrong? Where does that system notification icon is taken by the system?

Answer (score 3):

By default, a `VpnService`, like any `Service` inherits the icon from your application unless you specify one in your manifest via `android:icon`. You should create an icon per the [notification icon specifications](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#notification) (tools like [Android Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html) can help) and set that as the `android:icon` for your service:

```
<service android:name=".ExampleVpnService"
         android:icon="@drawable/notification_icon"
         android:permission="android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.net.VpnService"/>
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: have you tried this yourself? Seems that the 'key' icon is hardcoded for VPN

Comment: @KirillKarmazin There is a system-managed real notification with information that a VPN is running and shows information about the application which runs the vpn-service.
The 'Key' which is by default shown when a VPN is active is not a notification per se, but just an indicator in the status bar. It's not possible to modify the key of course, but the notification may be according to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that's not possible.

Pre-Lollipo, look at [Vpn.java:504](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/com/android/server/connectivity/Vpn.java#504) - it loads the launcher icon specifically. It seems quite deliberate - probably due to security concerns to prevent misleading the user.

Post Lollipop they [moved](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/05542603dd4f1e0ea47a3dca01de3999a9a329a9) it into Quick Settings UI, so I'm not sure there's an icon, but if there is, its probably hardcoded to use the launcher icon as well, for the same reasons.